# SQL query not inserting correct value to database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here is the SQL statement:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO MYIMAGES(image_blob, filename, description, filesize, accountnum, rmanum, billol, copiedfilename) VALUES(?, '"
SQL = SQL & File.Filename & "', '"
SQL = SQL & Replace(Upload.Form("DESCR"), "'", "''") & "', '"
SQL = SQL & File.Size & "', '"
SQL = SQL & Replace(Upload.Form("accountnum"), "'", "''") & "', '"
SQL = SQL & Replace(Upload.Form("rmanum"), "'", "''") & "', '"
SQL = SQL & Replace(Upload.Form("billol"), "'", "''") & "', "
SQL = SQL & Replace(Upload.Form("accountnum"), "'", "''") & "-" & Replace(Upload.Form("rmanum"), "'", "''") & ")"
```

accountnum = 3456345 rmanum = 345234

The value in the database that gets entered is `3111111` what I want it to be is `3456345-345234`

The data type of the column is `varchar(255)` - what am I doing wrong??

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), anyone?

Comment: If you output the sql variable, what does it look like?  Also, what field are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry it's the last one, the copiedfilename field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use sql parameters you can avoid `REPLACE` and also any sql injections

Ex:

Change sql statement to

```
INSERT INTO MYIMAGES(image_blob, filename, description, filesize, 
   accountnum, rmanum, billol, copiedfilename) 
VALUES(@p1, @p2, @p3,@p4,@p5, @p6, @p7,@p8)
```

Then do

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",File.Filename)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3",Upload.Form("DESCR"))
```

....

```
//this will insert correct data
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8",Upload.Form("accountnum") & "-" & 
                                  Upload.Form("rmanum"))
```

Updated based on OP comment: 
For ASP try this

```
dim cmd, rs, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5,param6, param7, param8
set cmd = server.CreateObject("adodb.command")
strCmd = "INSERT INTO MYIMAGES(image_blob, filename, description, 
            filesize, accountnum, rmanum, billol, copiedfilename)
            VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = objConn
cmd.CommandText = strCmd
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter ("image_blob", adWChar, adParamInput, 50)
param1.value = image_blob
cmd.Parameters.Append param1
....
Set param8 = cmd.CreateParameter ("copiedfilename", adWChar, adParamInput, 50)
param8.value = Upload.Form("accountnum") & "-" & Upload.Form("rmanum")
cmd.Parameters.Append param8
Set rs = cmd.Execute()
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll go with this one. Thanks all

Comment: It's saying Object required: 'cmd' when I try to submit the form. I need to create a command object first? This is an a classic ASP file btw

Comment: @user7954, yes you need to create command object, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO MYIMAGES(image_blob, filename, description, filesize, accountnum, rmanum, billol, copiedfilename) VALUES(?, '"
SQL = SQL & File.Filename & "', '"
SQL = SQL & Replace(Upload.Form("DESCR"), "'", "''") & "', '"
SQL = SQL & File.Size & "', '"
SQL = SQL & Replace(Upload.Form("accountnum"), "'", "''") & "', '"
SQL = SQL & Replace(Upload.Form("rmanum"), "'", "''") & "', '"
SQL = SQL & Replace(Upload.Form("billol"), "'", "''") & "', '"
SQL = SQL & Replace(Upload.Form("accountnum"), "'", "''") & "-" & Replace(Upload.Form("rmanum"), "'", "''") & "')"
```

I have just put ' to the begginning and end of the last value, so that it won't be interpreted as a mathematical expression

which is:

```
3456345-345234 = 3111111
```